# Andengine Live Wallpaper Texture issue

Tags: android, andengine, live-wallpaper

The texture on my live wallpaper is playing up...
I'm getting bad android reviews because of it.
The link below shows a texture problem on the bottom right hand corner.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/808/20120112200731.png/

It does not always do this but most of the times it plays up and at the different places.

Also does anyone know how to use the below cigarette live wallpaper example..
http://code.google.com/p/andenginelivewallpaperextension/
What I'm trying to do is make the smoke go from left side of the screen to the right...

At the moment the example shows the smoke will be going from bottom to the top of the screen.

Thanks

Wally